# How to create DropDownlist (Kendo UI for jquery) with list items having different font sizes

Tags: drop-down-menu, fonts, kendo-ui

I want to create a Kendo UI (for jquery) DropDownList with a few list items such that the font size of every list item is different. Lets say there are 3 items in the DropDownList, then each of the three must show in a different font size. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, one of possibilities is to return font size in datasource.

```
 var data = [
    { text: "Black", value: "1", fontSize: "12px" },
    { text: "Orange", value: "2", fontSize: "18px" },
    { text: "Grey", value: "3", fontSize: "24px" }
 ];
```

Then use kendo DropDownList templates for `valueTemplate` and `template`:

```
$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    valueTemplate: '<label style="font-size: #:fontSize#">#:data.text#</label>',
    template: '<label style="font-size: #:fontSize#">#:data.text#</label>',
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0,
    change: onChange
});
```

This is modified version of kendo example: [font size per item](https://dojo.telerik.com/ahOfInEy)

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was really helpful indeed. Cheers!